# Recording from XR18 to Tascam-DR40

Tags: audio-recording, recording, mixer, live-sound, tascam

I have a live performance that I'd like to record from the house Behringer XR18 mixer to a Tascam DR40. What's the best way to do this?  What exact cable and output source to the Tascam should I use?

One suggestion I got was to take the output from mixer TRS headphone jack and to the Tascam - is that the best way?

If that's the best way, is it a problem to take the TRS headphone signal and split it to the left and right channels that go into the Tascam?

Answer (score 0):

The XR18 has a number of output options. Personally, I would probably grab Aux 3 and Aux 4 and do my own mix on the Aux sends. Front of House mix is usually for sound reinforcement purposes and not specifically going to suit a recording, but it really depends on what instrumentation is on set.

If your username is any clue, then it might just be decks!

I'd still stay away from the headphone port though. The Tascam will take a couple of XLR inputs, so you should be able to configure that as line input and just do a left/right send on the aux buses. This will allow you to stay away from any monitoring the house engineer is doing.

Comment: My idea here is that the house main sound is mainly for reinforcing some instruments (guitar, bass), but other instruments don't need much help (brass). I want to use the Tascam in 4 channel mode, to grab the house mix, as well as the live sound from the center of the stage. Would using the AUX sends overpower the Tascam? And you're saying to use a XLR to Line cable to the Tascam, with the input setting set to Line and not Mic?

Comment: Yes, good call. This is exactly what I would do with that gear. Just don't go too close to the stage or it will sound boxy and small. Make sure you get back far enough to pick up room reverberation. As long as the XLR inputs are set to LINE level (and not Mic level) you will be fine with using an Aux mix.